# System Call Getting garbage value in file

Tags: c, system-calls

I am trying to write to a file using write system call, the file path passed through cmd line arg.
I am getting some garbage value, and i am not able to understand why this is happening.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>

#define FOUR 4

void odd_no (int fd)
{
  for (int i = 0; i < 20; i++)
    {
      if (i % 2 != 0)
      {
          write (fd, &i,FOUR);
      }
        
    }
}

int main (int argc, char *argv[])
{
  int fd;
  if (argc < 2)
    {
      printf ("Insufficient Arguments\n");
      return 0;
    }

  if ((fd = open (argv[1], O_WRONLY, S_IRWXU)) != -1)
    {
      odd_no (fd);
      close (fd);
    }
  else
    {
      perror ("open");
      exit(1);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: "_I am getting some garbage value_" what values are you expecting? How did you determine, that the values you get are garbage? How did you retrieve the values, via `read` or did you open that file in an text editor? Do not forget, that you are writing binary data to that file, not text.

Comment: OK, I am just writing instead of opening in program I am opening in text editor, but when I write char to the file it displays fine in text editor.

Comment: You are writing _binary_ data to the file and _not_ text. You can only view that with a hex editor. Do you want binary or text in the output file?

Comment: For text you want `fopen/fprintf`